# Best way to handle live updating of a user alerts panel

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, websocket

I would like to build a classic alerts panel using angular and java spring/spring boot  that responds to events and updates in real time so the user wouldn’t need to refresh the page to get their newest alerts. Because of the need for it to be live updating it seems like web sockets are my best bet.

After looking through some tutorials it seems that connecting to the backend socket from angular will be pretty easy and the connection can be turned on/off with ease. This will be using stompjs and sock js-client.

However it seems my issues will lie in the backend when creating the various ‘topics’ that users will subscribe to. All of these tutorials only cover creating a static room on server start that every user is supposed to join (like a chat app). But for my scenario I would need to dynamically create topics on the fly (one separate topic per user) instead of creating all of my topics in the beginning.

Anyone have experience using spring or spring boot to dynamically create the topics for my users to subscribe to?

Main tutorial I have been looking at is:
https://medium.com/oril/spring-boot-websockets-angular-5-f2f4b1c14cee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found that by using this in my controller:

```
@MessageMapping("/meeting/{roomId}")
private void sendMessageTpPrivateRoom(String message, @DestinationVariable String roomId) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("message sent to: " + roomId);
    this.template.convertAndSend("/meeting/" + roomId, message);
    addToHistory(roomId, message);
}
```

combined with this in my configuration:

```
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/socket")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
            .enableSimpleBroker("/chat", "/meeting");
}
```

I am able to have dynamically created chat rooms where clients in one room do not receive messages from clients in another